# Can I search for a contact using their Joomla UserID?

Tags: advanced-search

I need a way to find a list of contacts using a list of Joomla userIDs.
Eg: I have a list of Joomla userids (23,55,69,505,9949) -- how can I use civiCRM search to find the related contact records for those userIDs?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a search kit to find the contacts using  user id in (23,55,69,505,9949)

```
[
  [
    "SavedSearch",
    "save",
    {
      "records": [
        {
          "name": "Joomla_User_Contacts",
          "label": "Joomla User Contacts",
          "form_values": null,
          "mapping_id": null,
          "search_custom_id": null,
          "api_entity": "UFMatch",
          "api_params": {
            "version": 4,
            "select": [
              "uf_id",
              "contact_id",
              "contact_id.display_name"
            ],
            "orderBy": [],
            "where": [],
            "groupBy": [],
            "join": [
              [
                "Contact AS UFMatch_Contact_contact_id_01",
                "INNER",
                [
                  "contact_id",
                  "=",
                  "UFMatch_Contact_contact_id_01.id"
                ]
              ]
            ],
            "having": []
          },
          "expires_date": null,
          "description": null
        }
      ],
      "match": [
        "name"
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```